# Removing seconds from UnixTime Value

Tags: objective-c, unix-timestamp

So I have a unixtime datetime stamp. For arguments sake, lets say it's now at 23:49:24 on 21/02/2011 (GMT). This would be:

> 1298332164

Now, is there anyway to remove the seconds component from this? I'm writing this in Obj-C so currently I have:

```
NSDate *todayNow = [NSDate date];
int unixtimeNow = [todayNow timeIntervalSince1970];
```

And would end up with:

> 1298332140

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about 1298332164 / 60 * 60 ?

Comment: If you divide Y by X and then multiply Y by X you will end up with Y?

Comment: @ing0: No. This works because integer division in C strips the remainder of the division, so the result of `1298332164 / 60` is `21638869` and not `21638869.4`.

Answer (score 2):

In Cocoa, you can do it like this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger calendarUnits = NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [calendar components:calendarUnits fromDate:todayNow];
[dateComps setSecond:0];
NSDate *todayNowNoSeconds = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a play with NSDateComponents but didn't have much luck. Will try that thanks!

Comment: +1 Anyway. Your solution was more elegant but for cross platform the /60*60 was much simpler to implement!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSTimeInterval seconds =  fmod([self timeIntervalSince1970], 60);    
NSDate *secondsTrimmedDtae =  [self dateByAddingTimeInterval:-seconds];
```

Note self refers to `NSDate` instance you have to replace self with your date obj.